# Using regular Expression to replace emotions character in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have following JavaScript code.

```
var emoticons = {
    ':)': '<span class="emoticon emoticon_smile"></span>',
    ':-)': '<span class="emoticon emoticon_smile"></span>',
    ':(': '<span class="emoticon emoticon_sad"></span>',
    ':d': '<span class="emoticon emoticon_bigSmile"></span>',
    ':D': '<span class="emoticon emoticon_bigSmile"></span>'
}
```

and now to replace the emotion with span in the given text I am using following functions

```
function Emotions (text) {
    if (text == null || text == undefined || text == "") return;
    var pattern = /[:\-)(D/pPy@'*]+/gi;
    return text.replace(pattern, function (match) {
        return typeof emoticons[match] != 'undefined' ?
           emoticons[match] :
           match;
    });
}
```

Now the above code is working fine.If I pass the text in the function as below

```
Emotions("Hey this is a test :( :(");
```

see the space between 2 emotions character.
But if I remove the space between both the emotion then it does not work.Like below

```
Emotions("Hey this is a test :(:(");
```

There is something wrong with my regular expression but I am not been able to figure it out.

Comment: BTW, you can use: `return emoticons[match] || match;` instead.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/AbQ23/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
/:-?[()pPdD]/gi
```

characters in [] brackets are posibilites and remaining by order

Comment: Yes it should work fine indeed. When I wrote my answer, I had not noticed that all emotes would begin with `:`.

Comment: Although, that would match ":------D" which would result in a unnecessary function call since there is no emoji associated with that character sequence ;)

Comment: this is just a sample of emotions.I have others emotions in the list as well which are not starting with :

Comment: @VimalPatel as long as all of them start with a colon this should work fine. The dash (-) is optional as the asterisk (*) indicates

Comment: replace * with {0,1} then :)

Comment: Or replace it with `?` which is the shorthand for `{0,1}` ;)

Comment: as I have told there are many emotions which are not starting with :

Comment: ? means the - character whether or not exists is ok for the pattern

Comment: I have a emotion which is like this (cool) and above regEx will not work in this case.

Comment: @VimalPatel you have to somehow define how your emotions will be parsed. They may either start by `:`, or be separated by spaces, but if you set no rule at all I can't see how you could dissociate distinct emotions in strings such as `:)(cool)` (that's why I would use spaces like in my answer).

Answer (score 1):

The expression cannot tell that ":(:(" should be treated as two "blocks" since ":(:(" perfectly satisfies your regex `pattern`.

If you, for example, know that all your emojis start with a colon (:) you could use the following expression to check for emoji "blocks"

`:[\-)(D/pPy@'*]+` (the colon is now in front of the character-class)

Answer (score 0):

When you delete the space, your whole emotion sequence `:(:(` is match by your pattern `/[:\-)(D/pPy@'*]+/` (as a *single* sequence). As there is no span associated with `:(:(`, nothing is returned.

You should find a way to delimit your character sequence (e.g. by adding a space in front of your pattern like this `/ [:\-)(D/pPy@'*]+/`, but don't forget in that case to add a space in front of your span).

Comment: But then also it will only match 1 emotion not both.

Comment: @VimalPatel Absolutely right. I forgot ending `g`. It should be `/ [:\-)(D/pPy@'*]+/g`, or, even better (as in other answers), `/:[\-)(D/pPy@'*]+/g`

Answer (score 0):

try to change your regular expression to

`var pattern = /:[\-)(D/pPy@'*]+/gi;`

Comment: For future answers: Please consider outlining where OP went wrong with solving the problem, and outlining what changes you actually made instead of writing some code and leaving it to future visitors to figure out what exactly was the problem. It makes answers much more useful, and in this case even prevents your answer from being redundant.

Answer (score 0):

USe This Expresion search and your code will work

var pattern = /:[(-)dD]+/gi;